# Clean install ubuntu 16.04 cannot connect to wifi using NetworkManager, but nmtui works

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, asus, 16.04

I've performed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on my Asus N56VZ. Sadly, i cannot connect to wireless networks using the NetworkManager. I am able to see wireless networks, though.

I tried to connect to my network using the GUI and entered my password. But after that, nothing happens. I see no attempt to connect to this network, and I don't get an error either. I can see that the network manager saved my network, and I double and triple-checked whether the password and all other configurable parameters are correct.

Funny thing is - I am able to connect using `nmtui` without any problems.

I have not been able to test whether this is a problem with this specific network or if it is a general problem. I highly suspect the latter though, as I had no problem using said network on Ubuntu 15.04.

Output of some interesting commands:

Before connecting using `nmtui`:

`iwconfig`

```
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`lspci -vvnn | grep Network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
```

`sudo service NetworkManager status` (after I tried and failed to establish a connectiong using the NetworkManager)

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since So 2016-04-24 00:03:32 CEST; 15min ago
 Main PID: 788 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─788 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Apr 24 00:18:24 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449904.2249] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 24 00:18:24 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449904.2253] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 24 00:18:24 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449904.2265] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 24 00:18:24 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449904.2270] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 24 00:18:24 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449904.2277] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Apr 24 00:18:49 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <warn>  [1461449929.2418] device (wlp3s0): No agents were available for this request.
Apr 24 00:18:49 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449929.2419] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Apr 24 00:18:49 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449929.2422] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 24 00:18:49 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <warn>  [1461449929.2427] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'FRITZ!Box 7362 SL'
Apr 24 00:18:49 Tesla NetworkManager[788]: <info>  [1461449929.2437] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
```

After connecting, `iwconfig` yields:

```
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 7362 SL"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: 34:31:C4:30:7D:13   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:105   Missed beacon:0
```

I would be happy for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux. Version 14 the wireless worked fine but am seeing these symptoms on a clean install of 16.04

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried any further yet. After I connected via nmtui, everything worked; and I wasn't able to test it with an other network yet.

Comment: connecting to a wired network, getting the updates and enabling a third party driver fixed it for me

Comment: Could you please try to connect to a wireless access point and then  [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814)? It includes a bunch of other information that may be relevant under the circumstances like a kernel log excerpt (including messages from the wireless network adapter driver).

Comment: @Mesaph I cannot thank you enough for pointing `nmtui` out.

Answer (score 5):

I have been having the same issue, While not a fix, I found that restarting the network manager works. I have included the instructions to do this below.

From the command line

**Stopping Network Manager**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

**Starting Network Manager**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

Comment: This worked for me. Funny that it worked fine during the install as root, but not once my user was created. Is this due to the new user not being added to some kind of networking config?

Answer (score 3):

ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have properly configured wireless driver.. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in 3 machines and no one came with working wireless. Straight forward solution could be, user Ethernet cable to use Internet, then

- `sudo apt-get update`
- now goto > system setting > software updates > additional driver
- now if it shows wireless driver, install it and  you are done.

If it doesn't solves your problem you probably need to use logging tools like dmesg, syslog, journalctl, lshw.. know your wireless hardware and google the respective driver.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Your comment was so strong I believe it SHOULD have been an answer instead. Anyway, this comment-like answer saved my day ;)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by typing my password into a document, and then copying and pasting it into the password field.

For some reason the connection was timing out before I could type my (long) password in but not giving me any messages about it.

Comment: -1 Your case seems a bit different: you probably had a bogus non-printable character (e. g. a new-line character) in the wireless password when you pasted it from the clipboard. In OP's case the network manager complains that there was *no secret supplied at all* which is quite different from the *wrong* secret.

Comment: No, I have same fix. If you insert password fast - it works =)

Comment: Typing it into gedit and pasting it worked for me as well. How bizarre

Comment: @demon101: The question isn't about your or Anna's issue but about OP's. How do you know it was the “same fix” for them? They didn't accept an answer or comment positively on one.

Comment: @DavidFoerster your -1 is not justified. It exactly helped me to solve the same issue had. So I'll add +1.

Comment: THIS IS SO AMAZINGLY CORRECT!!! It has explained why I have never been able to connect my Ubuntu 16 to ANY wireless network. By pre-writing the pwd and pasting in the bloody pwd field I am now able to get rid of the ethernet cable everywhere. Well done, Anna!!

Comment: +1 because this has helped at least 3 users who have reported success.