# Upgrading Ubuntu 14 to 16 when I accidently pressed suspend

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, ecryptfs

I don't have any programing background.
So, I was upgrading the system via terminal, when it just started, i pressed suspend, instead of lock.
The screen froze. I switched it off. And when restarting, it give a terminal like screen. Asking for Login and password. I used ecryptfs to check if my partition still exists. I entered my login name and password and the mount passphrase. It works and indicated that the partition is mounted and decrypted.
So, I tried to do the same process using live CD. I get a response that my partition is recovered and mount. It asks for login credential, and it accepts it. But I face à problem with the mount passphrase wrapping.
Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want a Desktopenviroment back? As far as I understand, the system starts, but you're interface is missing. You can run this command, to see which version of ubunut is running: `lsb_release -a`. Please edit your question to give us this information too.

Comment: I will test it now, then edit the question.. Thank you

Comment: Check lsb_release - à. Réponse no lsb modules are available

Comment: I need the other lines ;-)

Comment: I apologize :). Distributor id: Ubuntu. Description: Ubuntu 16.04.06. Release: 16.04. Codename: xenial

Answer (score 0):

## Try to update and upgrade

You're setup seems to be interrupted during a update. But since you have a terminal infront of you, cou can still fix everything. Just run these commands and pay attention to the qesions asked on your screen:

```bsh
sudo -i # change user to root
apt update # get the newes information form the ubuntu repository servers
apt upgrade # installs the newer packages
```

I think, you will get some inforamtions during your the apt commands, espacially the last lines before you can enter something. I think they can helpo you too.

## Test internetconnection

You can test your internetconnection with these two commands.

```
host security.archive.ubuntu.com
ping -c 8 1.1.1.1
```

From your infromation given in the comments, it seems your network is not working.

If you got a Lan-cable, use it. Else, try `nmtui` or other suggestions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761532/clean-install-ubuntu-16-04-cannot-connect-to-wifi-using-networkmanager-but-nmtu).

Then run a testcomand from above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109531/discussion-on-answer-by-boba-fit-upgrading-ubuntu-14-to-16-when-i-accidently-pre).

Comment: I followed these commands : $ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
$ sudo dpkg --configure -à. Then I restarted. And chose the recovery mode. I found a new option to upstart the system. I chose it. It logged me in. I copied my files. And now I am upgrading the system, through the system update interface. Thanks a lot man for all the help. Mu ch appreciated

Comment: You must be carefull when you delete the lock-files, Be sure no apt or dpkg are running.
I'm happy you managed to fix and upgrade your installation.